# Twitter Bootstrap - Affix appear on offset

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How would I change the css display property when you scroll to the affix offset?

I want a div to appear when I'm midway down the screen but not visible until I hit my offset...

```
<div class="article-bar" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="700">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <?php include('inc_social.php');?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            Next: <?php next_post('%','');?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 .article-bar {width:100%; background-color:#FFF; padding:10px 20px; top:0; z-index:99999; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; display:none;}
```

Comment: Can you please show us some code or images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it! Don't forget to remove data-offset-top from the div.

```
 <div class="article-bar" data-spy="affix">
 ....
 </div>

 <script>
    $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() >= 700) {  
                $('.article-bar').fadeIn('fast');
            }else{
                $('.article-bar').fadeOut('fast');
            }
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Much simple, replace `else if($(window).scrollTop() <= 699)` with `else`. Both does the same in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start with a hidden element. This would work then:

```
<div class="article-bar" class="hidden" data-spy="affix">
....
</div>

<script>
   $(function() {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
         if($(window).scrollTop() >= 700) {  
            $('.article-bar').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.article-bar').fadeIn('fast');
         }else{
            $('.article-bar').fadeOut('fast');
         }
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: This did not work when I made the class hidden Bootstrap couldn't find the div.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution just using CSS

Add .hidden class to your element
Set .affix>.hidden to:  display:block !important

```css
 .article-bar {width:100%; background-color:#FFF; padding:10px 20px; top:0; z-index:99999; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.affix .hidden {
    display: block !important;
  }
```

```html
<div class="article-bar" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="700">
    <div class="row hidden"> 
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <?php include('inc_social.php');?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            Next: <?php next_post('%','');?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this.  Granted it affects all the affix items.

```
<div id="sticky-item">
   <a href="#somebookmark">TOP</a>
</div>

$('#sticky-item').affix({
  offset: 75
});

.affix
{
    left:20px;
    background-color:white;
}

.affix-top
{
    visibility:hidden;
}

$('#sticky-item').on('affix.bs.affix', function () {
        $('#sticky-item').fadeIn('slow');
});
```